# My CSS filepath is correct but it is not applying the css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code to the external CSS file. It was able to render my JavaScript but not my CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/styles.css"  type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the folder
[image]

What the website looks like
[image]

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong picture. Edited Picture. I tried the "../src/CSS/styles.css". It does not render still. If I move the styles.css to public and tried "styles.css" it works.

Comment: How do you know the CSS isn't loading? Do you see a 404 Not Found error in the network tab?

Comment: The project looks like I have not applied any styles. No background color, the text are not styled.

Comment: I think you should import the css file in your React JS file with something like `import "./styles.css";`

Comment: Can you share what you have inside your build folder?

Comment: thank you! using import "../styles.css"; works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put

```
<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"  type="text/css" />
</head>


OR


<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"  type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).